# Write a script to put a series of files in sequence

Tags: bash

I am beginning in scripting and I am trying to write a script in bash. I need a script to write a sequence of several file names that are numbered from 1 to 50 inside one file. These are trajectory files from MD simulations. My idea was to write something like:

```
for valor in {1..50}
do
echo "
#!/bin/bash
catdcd -o Traj-all.dcd -stride 10 -dcd traj-$valor.dcd" > Traj.bash
exit
```

However, I just got one file with the following line:

```
#!/bin/bash
catdcd -o Traj-all.dcd -stride 10 -dcd traj-50.dcd
exit
```

But what I really want is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
catdcd -o Traj-all.dcd -stride 10 -dcd traj-1.dcd -dcd traj-2.dcd -dcd traj-3.dcd ... -dcd traj-50.dcd
exit
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you are really trying to do but would something like this help?
`#!bin/bash`
`for i in $(<your sequence>)`
`do`
 `echo "my sequence: $i"`
`done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read a bit more about [bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion). You can do this:

```
{ 
    echo "#!/bin/bash"
    echo "catdcd -o Traj-all.dcd -stride 10" "-dec traj-"{1..50}".dcd"
    #                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} > Traj.bash
```

The underlined part is where the brace expansion will get expanded by the shell into
`-dec traj-1.dcd -dec traj-2.dcd ... -dec traj-50.dcd`

You don't need to explicitly end your script with `exit` -- the shell will exit by itself when it runs out of commands.

Answer (score 0):

`>` truncates the file on open. Either only use it once before the loop to create the file and then append (`>>`) within the loop, or redirect the entire loop.

```
> foo
for ...
do ...
  echo ... >> foo
done
```

...

```
{
  for ...
  do ...
    echo ...
  done
} > foo
```